# Request handle solrconfig.xml Spellchecker

Tags: solr, spell-checking

I am trying to set up spellchecker, according to [solr documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent). But when I am testing, I don't have any suggestion. My piece of code follows:

```
 <searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">

    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">textSpell</str>

    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="classname">solr.IndexBasedSpellChecker</str>
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">name</str>
      <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellchecker</str>
    </lst>
    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">textSpell</str>

  </searchComponent>


 <requestHandler name="/spellcheck" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <!-- Optional, must match spell checker's name as defined above, defaults to "default" -->
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
      <!-- omp = Only More Popular -->
      <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">false</str>
      <!-- exr = Extended Results -->
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">false</str>
      <!--  The number of suggestions to return -->
      <str name="spellcheck.count">1</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

The query I send to Solr:
q=%2B%28text%3A%28gasal%29%29&suggestField=contentOriginal&ontologySeed=gasal&spellcheck.build=true&spellcheck.q=gasal&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.collate=true&hl=true&hl.snippets=5&hl.fl=text&hl.fl=text&rows=12&start=0&qt=%2Fsuggestprobabilistic

Does anybody know why?? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your configuration looks correct. Can you post the query you're submitting, and expected results (i.e. what is in your dictionary)?

Comment: I input bsketball and I want to get basketball, for instance

Comment: Please post the entire query and all parameters you're posting to Solr. Do you have a document in your index that has the token 'basketball' in the textSpell field?

Comment: I edited my question qith this query information. Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, don't repeat `queryAnalyzerFieldType` twice in the component configuration.

It is recommended not to use a `/spellcheck` handler but instead to bind the spellcheck component to the standard query handler (or dismax if it is what you use) like this:

```
<requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
 <lst name="defaults">
    ...
 </lst>   
 <arr name="last-components">
    <str>spellcheck</str>
    ...         
 </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

You can then call it like this:
`http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=komputer&spellcheck=true`

Also don't forget [to build the spellcheck dictionary](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent#spellcheck.build) before you use it:
`http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=*:*&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.build=true`

You can force the dictionary to build at each commit by configuring it in the component:

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
 <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">textSpell</str>
 <lst name="spellchecker">
  <str name="classname">solr.IndexBasedSpellChecker</str>
  <str name="name">default</str>
  <str name="field">name</str>
  <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellchecker1</str>
  <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
 </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

Finally, make sure that your `name` field is really an indexed field of type `textSpell` and that it contains enough content to build a good dictionary. In my case, I have a field named `spellchecker` that is populated from a couple of fields of my index (using `copyField` instructions in the schema).

Comment: Acording to the dictionary, is this enaugh? <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">subject</str> or must I do simething else?

Comment: spellcheck.dictionary is not a not a config option but a request parameter to indicate which dictionary to use at runtime. It is useful if you have defined more than one dictionary.

Comment: I hav successfully build teh dictionary but when i run the url :http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=komputer&spellcheck=true i ma not getting any suggestion :(

Comment: It all depends on the documents you build your dictionary with. Do you have the word "computer" indexed somewhere?