# Problem with spellchecker

Tags: solr, spell-checking

Why I don't get any suggestion when I execute this query agains Solr:

> q=%2B%28text%3A%28gasal%29%29&suggestField=contentOriginal&ontologySeed=gasal&spellcheck.build=true&spellcheck.q=gasal&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.collate=true&hl=true&hl.snippets=5&hl.fl=text&hl.fl=text&rows=12&start=0&qt=%2Fsuggestprobabilistic

I am searching `gasal` and it should suggest `gasol`.
Thanks in advance

Comment: See my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967101/request-handle-solrconfig-xml-spellchecker

Comment: Do you get suggestions with any query? Or is it just with this query that you don't get the expected suggestions?

Comment: @Mauricio I don't get any suggestion

Comment: @Pascal thanks, but the configuration is right and I followed already your steps

Comment: And you have enough content in your dictionary? On doubt, you can examine the dictionary (it's a Lucene index by default) with Luke

Comment: I have over 30.000 index in my Solr!! All of them related with sports, so Gasol is there for sure. If I search 'gasol', I get results. Thanks for your answers @Pascal

Comment: But the Solr index and the dictionary are NOT the same thing! You sure you built your dictionary?

Comment: I have <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str> in solrconfig.xml, in the search component. Is it not enaugh?? Is it not loaded from the index automatically??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the spellchecker works by taking the indexed content of a source field (in Solr) and store into an external Lucene index. That external index is the dictionary. Each words of the source field are stored in the dictionary in a format that allows to match words that are closed to each other. When asking for suggestions, Solr will look into that dictionary, NOT into the Solr index.

So in order for the dictionary to be built, you have to specify the source field. It should be defined in your schema using an appropriate analyzer (usually no stemming). That field should contain enough words to built a good dictionary. A good practice is to populate it from your text fields using [copyfield](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields) instructions.

Then, the dictionary have to be built. This is the operation where the content of the source field is taken to build the actual dictionary. It can be done [automatically at each commit](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent#Building_on_Commits) or manually using the ["build" parameter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent#Quick_Start).