# spell check with haystack

Tags: django, solr, spell-checking, django-haystack

I am getting None in spell check

first i made changes in settings.py

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr',
        'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True,
    },
}
```

made changes in search_indexes.py

```
class JobIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    post_type = indexes.CharField(model_attr='post_type',faceted=True)
    job_location = indexes.CharField(model_attr='job_location',faceted=True)
    job_type = indexes.CharField(model_attr='job_type',faceted=True)
    company_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='company_name',faceted=True)
    job_title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='job_title', faceted=True)
    start_date = indexes.DateField(model_attr='start_date', faceted=True)
    end_date = indexes.DateField(model_attr='end_date', faceted=True)
    job_description = indexes.CharField(model_attr='job_description', faceted=True)
    country = indexes.CharField(model_attr='country', faceted=True)
    suggestions = indexes.FacetCharField()

    def prepare(self, obj):
        prepared_data = super(JobIndex, self).prepare(obj)
        prepared_data['suggestions'] = prepared_data['text']
        return prepared_data

    def get_model(self):
        return jobpost

    def index_queryset(self,**kwargs):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

Then made solr_schema replaced it rebuild index..looked solrconfig.xml for appropriate chnages.
Tested through django shell

```
>>> from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
>>> sqs = SearchQuerySet().auto_query('spider')
>>> suggestion = sqs.spelling_suggestion()
>>> print suggestion
>>> None
```

Got `None`, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You should rebuild your indexes using this command:

`python manage.py rebuild_index`

From [the docs](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html#SearchQuerySet.spelling_suggestion):

> To work, you must set INCLUDE_SPELLING within your connection’s settings dictionary to True, and you must rebuild your index afterwards. Otherwise, None will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

In order to spell-check using the SearchQuerySet, you need to bind the spellcheck component to the standard query handler.

This is done by adding this to your default requestHandler in the solrconfig.xml file:

```
 <arr name="last-components">
     <str>spellcheck</str>
     ...         
 </arr>
```

For more information, see this thread: [Solr spelling suggestions returns 'None'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967101/request-handle-solrconfig-xml-spellchecker)